# Error when deleting partner event source in aws EventBridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, salesforce, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to delete a partner event source in AWS EventBridge using the aws cli command

```
aws events delete-parter-event-source --region <region> --name <partnereventname> --account <accountnumber>
```

but I'm getting the error:

*Caller is not whitelisted for event source partner namespace aws.partner/salesforce.com*

The partner event is a Salesforce environment that was refreshed recently, so I need to delete the old partner event.

Someone know how can I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue *deactivated* the event source instead:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/events/deactivate-event-source.html

This command worked without any errors for me:

```
aws events deactivate-event-source --name <partnereventname>
```

The partner event source has now gone into a pending state. According to the linked doc, *"If it remains in PENDING state for more than two weeks, it is deleted."*

Comment: Hi Steve!! Thanks for your answer !! I had done your steps before your answer that and worked.